# Website is not updatable and if the website is stopped in IIS, it still works

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7

I'm thinking voodoo right now.

I've been messing with IIS for the past 3 hours to understand why a website can't be updated. Not only I can't update the website, but if I stop the application in IIS altogether, the website is still accessible from the server itself and from any other PC.

The website is [ThinkIncentive](http://thinkincentive.com). The application is currently stopped in IIS along with the associated application pool, but if you try it, you will be able to access it.

[image: Stop icon and tooltip saying that the application is stopped]

[image: Application pool is also stopped]

At first, I thought that the site was actually hosted somewhere else, so I resolved thinkincentive.com using an external tool, but it [match my server address](http://www.intodns.com/thinkincentive.com) at 70.38.31.170.

I tried to rename the application folder, but even with a different name, the site still works. So obviously, something else if feeding the site.

[image: Renamed folder]

If I stop IIS completely, the site no longer works, so IIS is hosting this web site.

I am a bit lost here. If someone has an idea or a tool that could help me understand this problem, it would be more than appreciated.

Comment: Maybe (just maybe) another site is responding to that host name (bound to a wrong site)) ? Stopping app pool shoul dhelp here (if that app pool is serving only that one site)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was hidden right in my face.

An integral copy of the website existed in the default IIS application and it was running on a different application pool. LazyOne comments sent me in the right direction

No matter if I changed or moved the files or if I stopped both site and application, the default application was picking up the request first and it was displaying its own copy of the website.

Comment: Ok? Which answer do you want me to vote up? I should as well close the question.

Comment: Whoops. The choices in the review didn't provide for this situation. I missed what you were doing. I'll delete my comment. Can you expand your answer a bit so that it explains the solution. LazyOne could delete his comment and then this answer is kind of meaningless.

Comment: I improved the answer.